# Flutter Image gallery saver - how to access path

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin, flutter-image, flutter-file

I'm using [Image gallery saver](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver) plugin for saving images. Method

`await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(pngBytes)`

returns an object

`{filePath: file:///storage/emulated/0/wallpapers/1608205629471.jpg, errorMessage: null, isSuccess: true}`

I'd like to get the path of the newly saved file (`/storage/emulated/0/wallpapers/1608205629471.jpg`).

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#maps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [Map](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#maps) object. Access the filePath `String` like so:

```
var response = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(pngBytes);

// value = json['key']
var path = response['filePath']; // 'file:///storage/emulated/0/wallpapers/1608205629471.jpg'
```

Comment: I thought this is a bad practice? Shouldn't you access it through some sort of a method? Also, should I just remove the 'file://' part and take the rest of the string?

Comment: This is not bad practice. It is an *Object* because everything is an *Object* in Dart. It is actually a primitive type in Dart (like *int*, *double*, *bool*, etc). This is how you access its values. And yes, just use *substring* to remove 'file://' if you need to.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the explanation. I didn't know it is a primitive type either. Hope I'll catch the train soon. Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the key from a map like this

```dart
final imagePath = result['filePath'].toString();
```

then if you need to get a location path removing `file://` with regular expression

```dart
final imagePath = result['filePath'].toString().replaceAll(RegExp('file://'), '');
```

[read documentation for more info](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.3/dart-core/RegExp-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

First You need to same the image id on database that you wants to retrieve.

Then pass the id with this method I am giving a snippet that I have used:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
Directory _appDocsDir;
        class ImageCashUtil {
      ImageCashUtil() {
        init();
      }
      init() async {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        _appDocsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        return _appDocsDir;
      }
    
      File fileFromDocsDir(String filename) {
        String pathName = p.join(_appDocsDir.path, filename);
        return File(pathName);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was wondering if there is another way, one that doesn't require you to give it your own file name.